# Unable to run serve . [basic html and app.js using npm install -g serve]

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to create PWA, not even reached that step though.
I created an index.html and empty app.js

I globally installed serve with `npm install -g serve`

when i give the command `serve .` [I am in the right directory]

I get the following error..

```
$ serve ./home/rohan/Work/programs/node-v6.9.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/serve/bin/serve.js:83
detect(port).then(async open => {
                  ^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

my node and npm versions are as follows
`v6.9.1` and `3.10.8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here. The issue is with node v6, which obviously does not have support for async/await (enabled in node since v7.6 and above).
So, you have to upgrade node to at least v7.6 to make it work...
I have upgraded node from v6 to v8 and now it works OK.

Comment: Yes, I had thought that much, did not want to upgrade incase it affects other projects in my system. But what the heck. Did it anyway, problem solved. Thanks @MagicWand (nice name, wink wink)

Comment: No problemo, I'm glad it helped!